# Bootstrap Slider Controls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/ which works a treat, however i'd like to output the value in realtime to an input box.

The js does this to a tooltip which is fine, however once you leave the slider, you can't see what you set it to.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Simply use the `slide` event thats supplied with the plugin. Scroll down to the bottom of the page you linked to and you should see an example.

Comment: this slider does not work in current Firefox `27.0`

Comment: Came across this on google, I'd like to plug [my fork of bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) which may help out those here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can log the slider value at real time using the `slide` event that is supplied with the plugin.

See this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/vMLPF/1/

**Code**:

```
$('#foo').slider().on('slide', function(_ev) {
    $('#bar').val(_ev.value);
});
```

In the above code, `#bar` represents the input box in which you want to show the slider value in real time.